# How to implement OnPropertyChanged event in partial class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to implement OnPropertyChanged event for a properties declared in partial class. I have POCO model classes generated by EF6. I want to apply some validations when the values of any properties are changed. Earlier version of EF would provide property changed methods which could be overridden. How can the same be achieved when using EF6?

Below, the first is EF generated entity & second class is what I am trying to achieve.

```
    public partial class Person
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Person
    {
        //On Address Property Chagned 
        // Set LastUpdatedBy
        // Set LastUpdatedDate
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if validation in DTO objects is the right thing

Comment: yes @Selvin agree. But, its not just a validation. On some of the property changes, there are some chain of events that are triggered. Its an old solution with more than 35 entities with such logic. If I could handle property changed event, I can easily modify the logic.

Comment: google: for code weavers C# ... i'm using Fody PropertyChanged (well not for EF because EF is bloated, but still)  also if it's EF6 not Core then you may change t4 file (how? there are already similar questions here on SO)

Comment: @Selvin I already saw one answer recommending Fody PropertyChanged. But, I quite didn't understand how to use it for my EF partial class. If you have link, that will help.

Comment: well it's in the official docs